# Get the Area details from AreaID in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, version-control

It seems there isn't any Database documentation for a given collection in TFS 2017 - e.g. DefaultCollection.

I can get WorkItems from `dbo.vw_WorkItemCoreAll` & `dbo.vw_WorkItemCustomAll`, but I can't seem to join on the `AreaID` that is given to `tbl_Area`.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no documentation because you're not supposed to directly query your project collection databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the joining has changed for TFS 2017.

In general I would ***recommend*** using the TFS_Warehouse, if the database must be used at all. Areas in TFS_Warehouse are much more straightforward than the TFS_[YOURCOLLECTION] Database.

That being said, if you must use the actual raw database, then here's a query that will join the necessary info:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_WorkItemCoreAll w
 INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ClassificationNode c ON w.AreaId = c.Id 
WHERE 
id = SOMEID
ORDER BY w.Rev DESC
```

It appears that tbl_Area doesn't contain the actual classifications used for WorkItems anymore.

---

***Disclaimer***: This is a last resort - the MSFT preferred mechanism for obtaining this info is the TFS REST API, for the usual API reasons (flexibility, reproducibility, etc.).

In this case I wanted to run an SSRS report (didn't care if it broke in a few months), which works better on raw DBs.

Comment: Users are stored in the `dbo.Constants` table